# Rails: Load js.erb file when page loads

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails

I am having a problem loading/rendering js.erb files when the page loads. It always displays as html.

This is what I have tried adding to my html.erb file on which I want my js.erb to load on:

```
<%=render 'employees_js.js.erb'%>
<%=render(:partial => 'employees_js.js.erb', :handlers => [:erb], :formats => [:js]) %>
```

It might be worth noting that I am trying to load this file on a template that is being loaded with AJAX.

Please let me know how I could load the js.erb file as js.erb and not .html.

Thank you.

Please let me know if I wasn't clear enough.

Comment: Before you spend anymore time going down this road, you should stop and try to do it the "Rails way" it will be much easier in the long run. This page is a good start http://guides.rubyonrails.org/working_with_javascript_in_rails.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't render a js partial in your html.erb with the `render` method. Render is going to be looking for an html file in this context. One workaround is to change your partial name to `employees_js.html.erb`, then wrap the javascript in a script tag.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  // your script
</script>
```

Then:

```
<%= render 'employees_js' %>
```

Sidenote: Rending javascript in rails should be done when it is explicitly requested, usually with a `remote: true` link or form. Otherwise, your javascript should be in the asset pipeline and requested with the `javascript_include_tag`.